# Filtering Date with remote data in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

My app have the same code as in the example grid-crud, all work ok with filtering, sorting, paging, etc.

But I have add some Date field, and the filtering is not working, this is the error:

Operator '<' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'String'

Is there something else to consider when use date fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just a though, but could you fetch your date field as a unix timestamp, and then use format to display it in user-friendly fashion?

```
{field: "MyDate", type:"date", format:"{0:d/M/yyyy}"}
```

... or something like that?